# Is there any way to determine the driving time between two locations using Apple's Maps API?

Tags: ios6, ios6-maps, driving-directions, driving-distance

I am evaluating using google's Distance Matrix / Places / Maps API, versus Apple's Maps api for an iOS app.

I am looking at the `MKDirectionsRequest` class, and I can't seem to find a way to determine what the driving time is between the two points. If this is possible using the apple Maps API, could someone please point me in the right direction?

I am hoping it would be possible to accomplish this just using Apple's API, but it looks like this is only going to be possible with Google's API.

Comment: The first answer is now outdated. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084304/calculate-time-taken-to-cover-a-journey-in-apple-maps.

Answer (score 2):

No, apple does not have any such way to get driving time between 2 locations. 

I'll suggest using Google API. Look at [Google Direction web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

Comment: Be careful, this is only allowed if you are actually display a map.