# What is proper way to get ETA (estimated time arrival) from any location to my current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, dictionary, mapkit

Would like to know what is proper way to get ETA (estimated time arrival) from any location to my current location, in consideration the following situation:

a. ex. - I got from another device its location (lon/lat) and want to when the other person will pick me up... In this case what web-service can I use to get this info for the user?
Does mapkit provides that kind of option?

b. In case it will be done on the server-side and I'll just send my user location, what are the tools my server-side programmer can use to get ETA info in order to send it back to my user?

Thank you all in advance.

I saw this: [Is there any way to determine the driving time between two locations using Apple's Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761157/is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-driving-time-between-two-locations-using-apple)
 - the problem, as I found in other places, (to my understanding)is that google api requires use of Google Maps app that isn't installed on every iOS user now.

Comment: You should look at some of the new SDK APIs in iOS 7.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know this post is a bit old but in case someone is looking at the answer since iOS 7 Apple provide an API in MapKit in order to calculate all these info.

Here is a snippet of how to use this API

```
    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    [request setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];
    [request setDestination:destination];
    [request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile];
    [request setRequestsAlternateRoutes:NO];
    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if ( ! error && [response routes] > 0) {
            MKRoute *route = [[response routes] objectAtIndex:0];
            //route.distance  = The distance
            //route.expectedTravelTime = The ETA
        }
    }];
```

Comment: did this method worked it is returning 0.00 in my case for any lat long... can you pls help i am struck in this.

Comment: Always use `firstObject` instead of `objectAtIndex:0`. Its crash proof and more clear

Comment: Thank you man. And i use another function to format the result.

Comment: But this ETA never works outside USA. I am trying it for china and everytime it returns no directions found :( could someone throw some light on this, what and all countries currently supports ETA feature right now?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me using   route.distance from M to the K's answer
I was modifying code from this tutorial [map directions tutorial](http://www.devfright.com/category/map-kit-framework/mkdirectionsrequest/)

```
(IBAction)routeButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    MKDirectionsRequest *directionsRequest = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:thePlacemark];
    [directionsRequest setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];
    [directionsRequest setDestination:[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark]];
    directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile;
    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:directionsRequest];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
        } else {
            routeDetails = response.routes.lastObject;
            [self.mapView addOverlay:routeDetails.polyline];
            self.destinationLabel.text = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"Street"];
            self.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f Miles", routeDetails.distance/1609.344];

            self.etaLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f minutes",routeDetails.expectedTravelTime/60];

            //self.transportLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u" ,routeDetails.transportType];
            self.allSteps = @"";
            for (int i = 0; i < routeDetails.steps.count; i++) {
                MKRouteStep *step = [routeDetails.steps objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString *newStep = step.instructions;
                self.allSteps = [self.allSteps stringByAppendingString:newStep];
                self.allSteps = [self.allSteps stringByAppendingString:@"\n\n"];
                self.steps.text = self.allSteps;


            }
        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: Did it worked ? its returning 0.00 in my case for any lat long can you pls help